# php js username live check

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a piece of my website application to give a life feedback whether a username is available or taken. I got to a dead end, and I'm wondering if I can get some help. Here is my js code:

```
$('#username').keyup(function() {


 var username = $(this).val();

$('#username_status').text('Searching...');

if (username !='') {
    $.post('username_check.php', { username: username}, function(data) {
        $('#username_status').text(data);
    });
} else{
    $('#username_status').text('');
}});
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  if (!empty($username)){
    $username_query = mysqli_query($con"SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'attendant' WHERE 'username'='$username'");
    $username_result = mysqli_result($username_query, 0);

    if ($username_result == 0) {
      echo 'Username availabe!';
    } else if ($username_result == 1){
      echo 'sorry, that username is taken.';
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($con"SELECT` <= *ahem*, something missing there ;-) Plus, wrong [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for `COUNT('id') FROM 'attendant' WHERE 'username'` - `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. Also `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires DB connection parameter. Fixing those may very well "fix" your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, as I've already outlined in a comment earlier, so I decided to post an answer in that regard, should you not have seen it. Many times, comments are unseen, and/or misunderstood.

- The *(something)* missing comma between `$con` and `"SELECT`
  `mysqli_query($con"SELECT` 
  which should read as `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT`
- [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) 
  requires a DB connection be passed as the first parameter.

Which should read as:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
```

- Using the wrong [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your table and columns, being quotes `'`

in:

```
SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'attendant' WHERE 'username'
             ^  ^       ^         ^       ^        ^
```

Either remove the quotes:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM attendant WHERE username
```

or replace them with backticks:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `attendant` WHERE `username`
```

---

**Debugging/troubleshooting:**

When writing code add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`
and use [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

***An insight:***

- Make sure that your form's elements corresponds to your variables.
- Plus, make sure your DB connection is `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO. Many times, people mix those different APIs together; they do not intermix. I say this because I don't know which API you are using to connect with; there is no indication of it in your code/question.

---

**Special note:**

- You should look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.